# Correct version of Ant not being picked by Linux

Tags: linux, ant

I get this really annoying message when working with ant on Linux. 
I export my `ANT_HOME=/home/ganesh/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502/bin`
Then i modify my path such as `export PATH=$ANT_HOME:$PATH`. But then when i run ant i get the error as `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher`. Should there be a bin at the end of the ANT_HOME variable? If i remove it, it still does not work. what is the issue? Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANT_HOME should point to the installation direcotry of ant. In this case, assuming the installation directory is org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502 and its layout is as follow 
`/home/ganesh/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502/{bin, lib, docs, etc}` then ANT_HOME should be

```
export ANT_HOME=/home/ganesh/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502
```

And the PATH should point to the directory having the ant binaries. such as

```
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```